# Leg vise - Planning for toe-in clearance on leg/chop vise screw holes

Tags: workbench, vises, leg-vise

I am building a workbench with a leg vise using a traditional parallel guide/pin board. The vise screw is an [off-the-shelf 18" metal vise screw](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01M2109GD), [image: vise screw]the legs are southern yellow pine and the vise chop is also southern yellow pine, 2" thick.

There is one thing I am not 100% clear on. I know that a leg vise chop doesn't remain parallel to the leg in use, to ensure the top contacts first and also because the pin board can only support so many discrete pin positions. But I have not seen many descriptions about where in the system the pivot occurs and planning for it.

Since the screw and the nut have some play, about 1-1.5°, and the handle/garter end of the screw does not, I am assuming that all that pivoting comes from the angle of the vise screw inside the nut. The nut is in theory rigid to the leg,  and the screw is in theory rigid with respect to the vise chop. To that end I am planning on drilling a tight hole for the vise screw on the chop side, and a slightly larger hole in the leg. The amount to over-size the leg hole I can calculate using trigonometry given the leg thickness and the expected pivot angle. (I suppose ideally it would be a tapered/conical hole but I'm not sure if I will go that far.)

However, I have never really seen anyone describe using a larger hole in the leg than the chop,  and I have also heard people say a leg vise chop bends in use, or that they install bushings somewhere in the system. Or, maybe people just let the screw chew out the space it needs in the leg hole in use. Anyway, I'm worried I'm missing something.

Is my plan to drill a larger hole in the leg to allow for the screw to pivot reasonable?

Comment: I may be missing something in your question, but any angle on the chop leg is set using the settings on the guide rail at the bottom.  I believe the screw hole should be drilled more or less level in the leg  and slightly larger than the screw to allow the screw to pass freely through the leg.

Comment: @Ashlar Yeah my question is about the "slightly larger." I can either drill it so it's just barely a clearance hole (say 0.005-0.010" larger diameter than the screw) or I can drill it so there's enough room for the screw to pivot +/- 1° in the nut (which would be more like 0.100"-0.125" oversize.)

Comment: It does not matter, the threaded rod is held horizontal by the mounting plate/nut that screws to the leg.

Comment: @Ashlar Okay, so I'm lost as to how this whole mechanism is supposed to work, then. I'm going to draw some pictures and update the question.

Comment: I actually went and looked at my vise hardware again and I was wrong, there is play in both the nut that attaches to the bench leg and the plate that attaches to the moving jaw, relative to the screw. So I suppose that explains where the pivot develops: The screw does not remain perpendicular to the movable jaw. Sound right?

Comment: @ScottHilbert that sounds right, if I'm understanding. These vices are intended to not grip square, but true to the piece up to some maximum.

Comment: Scott, if you're still monitoring this Q a piece of advice I commonly give out is not to reinvent the wheel if possible — just find some leg vice builds online and basically copy it. I think James Wright of Wood By Wright on YouTube has a leg vice on his bench so you'll probably find a build vid on his channel. Then if you want to improve on the setup further line one or both chops with leather, which in addition to (greatly) improving grip has other advantages.

Comment: @Graphus I am following some plans in Chris Schwarz's workbench book, but the plans say the holes in leg and chop are both 1-3/8" with the note "Dimensions to suit vise hardware." But I don't know what dimensions "suit" my vise screw, which is 1.167" in diameter. I could ask that as a whole new question if that makes more sense.

Comment: The exact hole size probly isn't critical because it's deliberately sloppy (loose fit, no implication of inaccuracy with that word here). If you're following along with Schwarz's book here's what you could do: convert his numbers into decimals so you can do a better like-for-like with what you have, then drill your holes accordingly. Remember you can test drill in two pieces of scrap anything (solid wood, ply or MDF) to see if it'll work right. If you then find the hole in the moving jaw needs to be enlarged that's easy to do with a round file or just abrasive wrapped around a dowel. [contd]

Comment: If you think you need more input on this it's a query better put to a forum membership than asked here where the idea is to provide a single canonical or definitive Answer. With a large — much more active! — community of woodworkers you're more likely to find people with relevant experience anyway. You could start with the Reddit woodworking forum and if you don't get what you need SawMillCreek may be the best second port of call.